# In the netty library, i want to know how to create multiple thread according the cpu number?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

In the netty library, i want to know how to create multiple thread according the cpu number? would you give me some example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is anything specific about multithreading in netty. In Java, you can find the number of processors with this command:

```
final int NUM_PROCESSORS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

You can then create a thread pool of that size with an executor for example:

```
final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_PROCESSORS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using nio, then you can pass the number of worker threads to use in the constructor of `NioServerSocketChannelFactory` or `NioClientSocketChannelFactory`. If you do not specify a value then Netty defaults to `(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2)` worker threads.